# Nativescript angular 2 component how to?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How do i implement a component like a element directive in angular 1?

This is my code but it doesn't work:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: "TestComponent",
    selector: "TestComponent",
    template: '<Label text="TEST COMPONENT" textWrap="true"></Label>'
})
export class TestComponentComponent {
    constructor() { }
}

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="TEST"></Label>

        <TestComponent></TestComponent>
    </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("third-party-view", () => require("./third-party-view").SimpleTag);
```

You can read more about it: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/plugins/angular-third-party.html

Comment: Got it to work by adding the component to "declarations" in the @NgModule